# How do I create sub-pages for a custom content type?

Tags: views, 8, navigation

In Drupal 8, I'd like to create a set of page that relate to a parent content type as so:

1. Movie (site.com/movie-name)

   - Reviews (site.com/movie-name/reviews)
   - Actors (site.com/movie-name/actors)
   - ...

I'd like each child to be it's own page, but retain some information from the parent (e.g. Movie Title, Movie Image, etc.).  Also, I'd like to display a menu navigation that is smart enough to adapt to each parent (perhaps a simple menu with relative paths would suffice?).

I imagine that I'll want to use views to accomplish this.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [Entity Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUx0ZlSGwiM) field

Answer (score 0):

In order to have reviews, you can use Comments entity on your movie content type.

For Actors you can create a separate content type and keep a reference of actors content type on movie, so that you can reuse actors on different movies.

and then views will help you in bulding different flavours of pages.